# IS atul sharma world's fastest bowler?

Tags: cricket, trivia

In 2009, some news came that atul sharma is worlds fastest bowler. Rajastan Royals picked him to their squad.

So i just wanted to know that is it a fake news?? He hasn't played even a single domestic match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Guinness Book of Records](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/records-10000/fastest-bowl-of-a-cricket-ball/) Shoaib Akhtar is the bowler who delivered the fastest recorded delivery.

Comment: this is not the answer am looking for

Comment: Sorry about that - but you asked if that news is fake. According to the link I supplied, he is not the world's fastest bowler, and hence the news IS fake. I'm not sure how else the question could be answered.

Comment: here am asking about a particular person Athul Sharma...

Comment: Re-read your question - it asked "is this fake news?" - the answer to that question is Yes. If you meant to ask "Is Athul Sharma the fastest bowler in the world?" the answer is No. I'm not sure how we can further assist you, especially if don't actually ask the question you're interested in - we're not psychic, you know.